# Mutation of non-conformable arrays

Tags: r, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, data-science

```
library(boot)
install.packages("AMORE")
library(AMORE)

l.data=nrow(melanoma)
set.seed(5)
idxTrain<-sample(1:l.data,100)
idxTest<-setdiff(1:l.data,idxTrain)

set.seed(3)

net<-newff(n.neurons=c(6,6,3),
        learning.rate.global=0.02,
        momentum.global=0.5,
        hidden.layer="sigmoid",
        output.layer="purelin",
        method="ADAPTgdwm",
        error.criterium="LMS")

result<-train(net,
         melanoma[idxTrain,-2],
         melanoma$status,
         error.criterium="LMS",
         report=TRUE,
         show.step=10,
         n.shows=800)
```

The problem I have is I have an error in result: "target - non-conformable arrays".
I know that it is the problem with **melanoma$status**, but have no idea how to alter the data accordingly. Any ideas? Couple of samples of data (if you don't use boot package from Rstudio).
melanoma:

```
        time status sex  age year thickness ulcer
    1     10      3   1   76 1972      6.76     1
    2     30      3   1   56 1968      0.65     0
    3     35      2   1   41 1977      1.34     0
    4     99      3   0   71 1968      2.90     0
    5    185      1   1   52 1965     12.08     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your target variable should first take only the training indices. Moreover, the target should have a number of columns equal to the number of classes - with one-hot encoding. Something like this:

```
net<-newff(n.neurons=c(6,6,3),
       learning.rate.global=0.02,
       momentum.global=0.5,
       hidden.layer="sigmoid",
       output.layer="purelin",
       method="ADAPTgdwm",
       error.criterium="LMS")

Target = matrix(data=0, nrow=length(idxTrain), ncol=3)
status_mat=matrix(nrow=length(idxTrain), ncol=2)
status_mat[,1] = c(1:length(idxTrain))
status_mat[,2] = melanoma$status[idxTrain]

Target[(status_mat[,2]-1)*length(idxTrain)+status_mat[,1]]=1

result<-train(net,
          melanoma[idxTrain,-2],
          Target,
          error.criterium="LMS",
          report=TRUE,
          show.step=10,
          n.shows=800)
```